# Remove inline style created from jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

On one page I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete, which creates rather annoying inline styles like setting the generated ul to width: window.width. That messes up my styles and is, at least for my taste, completely useless.

Is there any elegant way of getting rid of these inline styles other than "!important"?

EDIT:
I build a little [jsfiddle for my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/soq2g5vb/10/).
As you can see when you type in a charackter the ul is set to have the full windows width, which is applied inline. I even tried `width: initial!important` on that ul which doesn't work.
However, I figured out in the fiddle, when I loaded the default jQuery UI theme it looks fine.
But in the Theme Roller there is no option weather or not you want your uls the full windows width.

Comment: did you used that particular classes to use your own CSS instead of default css?

Comment: can you please add you code here or in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the style attribute and then add it again (if you need it empty)

```
function reset(this)
{
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
  $(this).attr('style','');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately NO

Inline style has top priority and the element having inline style will ignore any matching styles declared in css file.

If you want to do it with just css so the only option to di it is to define css with `!important` to overwrite it.

Or use JS solution.

```
$('element').removeAttr('style');
```

> But i would say using css solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below script to set your own css to instead default inline styles

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $("Your-class").css("any-proprty", "value");        
});
</script>
```